# Small parameter expansion to obtain convective heat transfer solution of the heat equation

Tags: thermodynamics, perturbation-theory, convection, transport-phenomena

I'm trying to follow along with [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1088/0741-3335/37/8/001) on perturbative transport analysis. The section I'm stuck on analyzes the heat equation in 1D slab geometry. To get a diffusion-only solution is relatively simple, but the paper then continues by doing a small parameter expansion to include the effect of convection and skips a couple of steps so that I get lost in the derivation and I don't know how to arrive at the same result. Can someone help me to fill in the blanks?

The starting equation is as follows (there is a reactive/damping term as well but for now I'd be happy just figuring out the convection so I've omitted it here):

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}u = D\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}u + V \frac{\partial}{\partial x}u,$$
with boundary conditions $u(x=0,t) = u_0\rm{e}^{i\omega t}$ and $u(\infty,t) = 0.$

For the simple case with diffusion only ($V = 0$), the solution is given by:
$$u(x,t) = u_0\rm{e}^{-x/\lambda_d}\rm{e}^{i\left(\omega t - kx\right)}.$$

From this, you can see/derive that the amplitude decays with characteristic length $\lambda_d = \sqrt{\frac{2D}{\omega}}$ while the phase velocity $v_{\phi,d} = \omega/k$ is given by $v_{\phi,d} = \sqrt{2\omega D}$.

Now, we can quantify the relative importance of diffusion and convection by introducing normalized time $\theta = t/(\lambda_d/v_{\phi,d})$ and normalized distance $\xi=x/\lambda_d$:
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}u = 2\frac{\partial^2}{\partial \xi^2}u + \varepsilon_V \frac{\partial}{\partial \xi},$$

with the dimensionless parameter $\varepsilon_V = V/\sqrt{2D\omega}$.

Now, up to here, all is fine and dandy, and I can follow along just fine. However, what comes next is too big of a jump for me.

The paper goes on to say "[...] the effect of convection can be appreciated from an expansion in the small parameter $\varepsilon_V$", and gives the result as follows:
$$\lambda = \lambda_d\left(1-\varepsilon_V + O(\varepsilon_V^2)\right),$$
$$v_{\phi} = v_{\phi,d}\left(1-\frac{1}{4}\varepsilon_V^2 + O(\varepsilon_V^4)\right).$$

While I understand the principle of small parameter expansion, I can't figure out how to get to this result in this case. Can anyone show me how to get there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let me note that the dimensionless equation in the OP has an incorrect factor, it should read:
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}u=\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial \xi^2}u+\varepsilon_V\frac{\partial}{\partial \xi}u
$$
The dimensionless solution at $V=0$ is
$$
u_0=e^\xi e^{i(\theta-\xi)}.
$$
The full equation can be solved exactly by first factoring out the time dependence,
$$
u(\xi, theta)=u(\xi)e^{i\theta}\Rightarrow iu(\xi)=\frac{1}{2}u''(\xi)+\varepsilon_V u'(\xi)
$$
One can then look for the solutions in the form $u\propto e^{\lambda \xi}$, which results in characteristic equation
$$
\lambda^2+2\varepsilon_V\lambda - 2i=0.
$$
If $\varepsilon_V=0$, teh roots of this equation are $\lambda=\pm(1+i)$, of which only the second gives us the solutions decaying for $\xi\rightarrow +\infty$.

The roots of the full characteristic equation can be approximated as
$$
\lambda_{1,2}=-\varepsilon_V\pm\sqrt{\varepsilon_V^2+2i}=
-\varepsilon_V \pm\sqrt{2i}\sqrt{1+\frac{\varepsilon^2}{2i}}\approx
-\varepsilon_V \pm (1+i)(1-\frac{\varepsilon^2}{4i}),
$$
where I used the Taylor expansion for the square root, $\sqrt{1+x}\approx 1 + x/2$.

Since $\varepsilon_V\ll 1$, the decaying solutions will be again given by the root with minus sign, i.e.,
$$
\lambda = -1-\varepsilon_V-\frac{\varepsilon_V^2}{4}-i(1-\frac{\varepsilon_V^2}{4})
$$
(The $\frac{\varepsilon_V^2}{4}$ in the real part can be omitted, since it is much smaller than the linear term in $\varepsilon_V$.)

The solution is then
$$
e^{-(1+\varepsilon_V)\xi-i(1-\frac{\varepsilon_V^2}{4})\xi}=
e^{-(1+\varepsilon_V)\frac{x}{\lambda_d}-i(1-\frac{\varepsilon_V^2}{4})\frac{\omega x}{v{\phi,d}}}=
e^{-\frac{x}{\lambda}-i\frac{\omega x}{v{\phi}}},
$$
from which we identify
$$
\lambda = \frac{\lambda_d}{1+\varepsilon_V}\approx\lambda_d(1-\varepsilon_V),\\
v_{\phi}=\frac{v_{\phi,d}}{1-\frac{\varepsilon_V^2}{4}}\approx
v_{\phi,d}(1+\frac{\varepsilon_V^2}{4})
$$

---

Let's write the equation as
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}u-2\frac{\partial^2}{\partial \xi^2}u=\epsilon_V\frac{\partial}{\partial \xi}u = f(\xi,\theta)
$$
If $f(\xi,\theta)$ were a given function independent on $u$, this could be easily solved (a sum of the general solution of the homogeneous equation plus the particular solution of the inhomogeneous one).

In our case it depends on $u$, which can be represented as a Taylor expansion in the small parameter $\epsilon_V$:
$$
u(\xi,\theta)=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\epsilon_V^n u_n(\xi,\theta),
$$
where $u_0(\xi,\theta)$ is the solution of the equation without the convection term, that we already know, and $u_n$ do not contain the small parameter $\epsilon_V$.

If we plug this into the expression for $f(\xi,\theta)$ we get
$$
f(\xi,\theta) = \epsilon_V\frac{\partial}{\partial \xi}u = 
\epsilon_V\frac{\partial}{\partial \xi}\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\epsilon_V^n
u_n(\xi,\theta)
\approx
\epsilon_V\frac{\partial}{\partial \xi}u_0(\xi,\theta),
$$
where in the last approximate equality I kept only the term of the first order in $\epsilon_V$. Thus, one needs to solve
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}u-2\frac{\partial^2}{\partial \xi^2}u=\epsilon_V\frac{\partial}{\partial \xi}u_0.
$$

Comment: Could you please make explicit the link between this answer and the last two equations in the question?

Comment: @Chemomechanics In fact, I think one could get faster to the result by solving the problem exactly and making expansion in the small parameter in the roots of the characteristic equation. I will post it, if I have time to do the calculations.

Comment: @Chemomechanics I posted how to derive the final result. It is worth rechecking it, since I get a different sign in the correction to the phase velocity.

Comment: Thank you Roger! This answer is a useful resource.